# how to pull parent term from nested array?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm building a custom field and formatter in Drupal 8(and teaching myself how to use Drupal & PHP, so bear with me)

I'm not sure how to pull a parent term 'name' value from a nested array.

Right now, I've got this:

```
$tid = 15
$parent = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadParents($tid);
```

But I'm not sure how to get the 'name' field so I can use it in my #markup.

I used var_dump to see what was there (can't use kint at the moment. Devel caused issues with some other modules)

Here's the array that came back:

```
array(1) { 
[3]=> object(Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term)#1187 (26) { 
    ["values":protected]=> array(9) { 
        ["tid"]=> array(1) { 
            ["x-default"]=> string(1) "3" 
        } 

        ["vid"]=> array(1) { 
            ["x-default"]=> string(10) "plant_part" 
        } 

        ["uuid"]=> array(1) { 
            ["x-default"]=> string(36) "2xxxxxx6-5xxb-2xx5-8xx7-axxxxxxxxc" 
        } 

        ["langcode"]=> array(1) { 
            ["x-default"]=> string(2) "en" 
        } 

        ["name"]=> array(1) { 
            ["x-default"]=> string(11) "Term wanted" 
        }
```

I was trying something like this, but no luck:

```
 $parent['values']['tid']['x-default']
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please check my answer below. But also note, that this group is not intended to teaching you programming. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check closely with the `var_dump()` output, you will see, that you actually load an array of entity objects with the type taxonomy term: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/class/Term/8.5.x

This object has a getter method `getName()` that returns the desired property:

```
$names = [];

foreach($parent as $term) {
  $names[] = $term->getName();
}

$names_list = implode(', ', $names);
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for asking such a generic programming question. getName() was exactly what I was missing!